# Create an array if threads in java and run

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a function that creates several threads.For each thread,a constructor takes an object from a different class, so I have first to create an object of this class and then create the thread. Below the code(modified for the simplification of example)

```
public static void createThread (int n) {
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         someClass obj=new someClass(i);
         ThreadClass myThread=new ThreadClass(obj);
         myThread.run();
        }
```

The problem here is that I don't really see that threads are running randomly. I am printing each one of them on run() and I see that they are displayed in their order. Is anything wrong with this? Should I run it differently?

Thanks

Comment: Use myThread.start(), not myThread.run().

Comment: Add objects to the list and call them randomly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Thread.start()` rather than `Thread.run()`. Using the `run` method simply calls that method in the same thread, whereas the `start` method actually creates a new thread and calls the `run` method within that thread.

I assume by "randomly", you actually mean interleaving. This should lead to that result.

Comment: @Cratylus.. From OP's explanation, and his code, it is almost clear that his `ThreadClass` either extends `Thread` or implements `Runnable`.

Comment: Yes, you're right ThreadClass extends threads. I used start() and suceeded,thanks!!!